# Any Button to Save Position and Rotation in Animation 3Ds Max

Tags: 3dsmax

I have a problem in 3ds max. I build an animation based on bone with some controllers. Let say I have an arm controller (please see the attached image) and I want it to be animated from frame A, B, and C.

http://tinypic.com/r/11i08iq/8

From A to B, I animated the controller using the Move tool. Then right at the C frame, I like to make it rotated about 50 degrees. Using the auto key, the controller will start the automatic rotation from the frame A as shown as the green line. Here I want it to be start only from B like the white line. So whether 3ds max has manually saving features, so that I can keep all the position and rotation from the controller at the selected frame B?

Right now I can fix this by changing the value of the rotation on the controller selected in frame B, but it is very time consuming and ineffective. I've been searching this behafiour at google but all they said is how saving and load the animation, I don't have any idea to search right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to set the slider to frame B, then press the 'Set keys' button, (the big button with a key on), this will create a keyframe for the object at frame B, then move the slider to frame C and set the key for your rotation there with the 'set keys' button, or just use autokey feature.

The default behaviour for 3dsmax keyframes is for them to start at frame 0 when you use autokey when there is no keys yet.

Comment: oohh my gosh, how long I've been missed this thing... Thanks Stig